# javascript intellisense and input name="Date"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, javascript-intellisense

Naming an input field 'Date' screws up javascript intellisense in my Visual Studio 2012. Makes me wonder if this is considered bad practice?

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    d. <-- no intellisense
</script>
<input type="text" name="Date" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's better not to use languages reserved words, there are sometimes ways to scape them, but it could confuse yourself in the future if you need to modify something anyway, or even worse, if somebody else needs to modify your work.

You can always use intuitive prefixes for example:

```
myDate
inputDate
formDate
etc
```

Comment: Thanks, your way is the best. I was a bit perplexed by the Visual Studio intellisense-bug and wanted to get it up here to help others searching for it.